# How to show and hide div using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I know that my problem could seems really easy to solve (or to find a solution on google), but i think it's a bit more complicated than what i could have wrote in the title...

I need to create something like facebook notifications: every X seconds, a query is launched through Ajax to check if a value on the DB is 0 or 1, and if it's 0 the div appears!

Here how i've managed to do this

The code to print the div:

```
function stampa_new_friend_request() {

return "<script> 
    window.setInterval('controllaAmicizie()', 500); 
    </script>

    <div id='friend_request'> 
    </div>";}
```

The JS functions

```
function setXMLHttpRequest(handler) {
    var xhr = null;

    if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if ( window.ActiveXObject ) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
    return xhr;
}

function handler() {
    if (myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status == 200) {
        riempi_friend_request(myRequest.responseText);}
}


function controllaAmicizie() {
    myRequest = setXMLHttpRequest(handler);
    myRequest.open('GET','friend_notification.php');
    myRequest.send(null);
}

function riempi_friend_request(richiesta) {
    var div = document.getElementById("friend_request");
    if (div.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
        div.style.visibility = 'visible';
        div.style.display = 'block';
    } 
    else {
        div.style.visibility = 'visible';
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }       

    div.innerHTML = "<p><a class='alert' href='friend_request.php'>" + richiesta + "</a></p>";
}
```

And the PHP page friend_notification.php

```
<?php 

include("functions/layout_functions.php"); 
include("functions/db_functions.php");

$mysqli = connetti_db(); 
session_start();

$query = "SELECT * FROM amici WHERE id_ricevente =".$_SESSION['id']." AND      user_ricevente='".get_user()."' AND confirmed = '0'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if (mysqli_num_rows ($result) > 0) echo "Hai ".mysqli_num_rows ($result)." nuove richieste di amicizia";

else if (mysqli_num_rows ($result) == 1) echo "Hai ".mysqli_num_rows  ($result)." nuova richiesta di amicizia";

disconnetti_db($mysqli);

?>
```

Everything works pretty well, but when i refresh the page the `div` takes half a sec to show itself (because of the `setInterval()`): when the `div` is shown for the first time (and so when the query find a result) i would like it to stay visible until the query result will be 0 (and not to "recharge" it every time i refresh the page).

Sorry for my baaaaaad english, i hope you could understand my problem!

Thanks!!

Comment: Set the interval a little higher. You could flood the server with requests. Or better set a new timeout everytime a ajax call succeeded or failed

Comment: You can just call `controllaAmicizie()` immediately after you call `setInterval()` to show the DIV when the page loads.

Comment: Ty! Calling controllaAmicizie() after callign setInterval() solved the problem just in part, since there is still a little delay between the page layout loading and the div showing! It's better than before for sure, but i would like to remove that delay at all!

Answer (score 0):

Call the function to show the DIV immediately when the page loads:

```
function stampa_new_friend_request() {

    return "<script> 
            window.onload = function() {
                window.setInterval(controllaAmicizie, 500); 
                controllaAmicizie;
            };
            </script>

            <div id='friend_request'> 
            </div>";
}
```

BTW, it's better to pass a function to `setInterval` than a string.

Comment: Uhm... if i put the <script> bla bla bla </script> in onLoad the div never shows! Probably  i haven't understood as well your solution XD

Comment: I've changed my answer to show how to do it with `window.onload`.

Comment: Right... Soz, didn't see that! Well this doesn't solve the problem, the timing of the div showing is still half a second on every reload

Comment: I think you won't be able to reduce that time, because that half a second is the time that the ajax request is taking to complete. Remember that the request may travel no another page and then come back.

Comment: Uhm... and is it possible to find a way, for exaple, to make that request only on the first load? I mean... I get the page and the div appears for the first time. Then, when i refresh (or get on another page, the div will be printed on more pages with the same function), since it was already shown, the request will only refresh what i've wrote in the div and not open and close the whole box

Answer (score 0):

```js
function controllaAmicizie_fake() {
  myRequest = doPost();

}


function riempi_friend_request(richiesta) {
  var div = document.getElementById("friend_request");
  if (div.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
    div.style.visibility = 'visible';
    div.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    div.style.visibility = 'visible';
    div.style.display = 'block';
  }

  div.innerHTML = "<p><a class='alert' href='friend_request.php'>" + richiesta + "</a></p>";
}

document.getElementById("friend_request").className = "hide";

//this fakes a call to the server
//I can't really do a server call in the code snippet
//This is a proof of concept. You should implement the idea of doPost into your own code inside the function handler.

function doPost() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)

  if (random) {
      riempi_friend_request("New friends");
      document.getElementById("friend_request").className = null;
  }
  else {
     document.getElementById("friend_request").className = "hide";
  }
  document.getElementById("serverPoll").innerHTML += "Server Poll returns: " + (random ? true : false) + "<br />"; 
  
  window.setTimeout(controllaAmicizie_fake, 1000); //wait another second to do a new poll.
}
controllaAmicizie_fake();
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="friend_request"></div>


<div id="serverPoll"></div>
```

This code gives an example of what I mean. It will directly execute on the page due to `controllaAmicizie_fake();` being called at the bottom of the script. In your code this is `controllaAmicizie()`. Then a HTTP request is launched. If it returns a new timeout is created that fires another server poll.

Different from your code is the existence of the friend div on the page. It's created when the page loads and is hidden away by the code. Every time the server returns true, it's get shown.

Comment: I've pasted the code you wrote in my file, adding controllaAmicizie_fake, doPost and "document.getElementById("friend_request").className = "hide" in reimpi_friend_request. Then i've added the .hide class and the "serverPoll" div after the "friend_request" one! But the result is always the same... Where i'm wrong?

Comment: @SimoneBancaSerra as I said, my code is just to show you how it can work. It should not be copy pasted into your own solution. You need to edit your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, i solved this... It's a bit tricky but it works! Everytime the query finds a result it set a session variable like "you have 1 request" (like the echo), and when it finds no more results it unsets the variable and echo "0". The js, before showing the div, check if "risposta" (that is the echo from the php) is !=0: yes, there are new requests, so show the div; no, no new requests, keep the dive hide.

Then in the html page i have 2 scripts: the first, if the session variable is set, print the div filling it with the variable itself (without asking everytime to the db with ajax); the second, if the variable is unset, runs ajax to look for new requests (and this solved the "loading instant" on every refresh).

Then i've got this minor problem: i have this notification on the left "1 request" and the page on the right, with the form to accept the request. If i accept it, the notification chills on "1 request" until i refresh the page. I solved this with an "else if (richiesta == 0)" in the js code: if it's true, it forces the value of richiesta to "no new requests" and print it in the div, replacing the old "1 new request" from the session value!

Here the code

HTML code to print and fill the div

function stampa_new_friend_request() {//stampa il div se ci sono nuove richieste di amicizia

```
if(isset($_SESSION['request'])){
return "<div id='friend_request' class='show'><p><a class='alert' href='friend_request.php'>".$_SESSION['request']."</a></p></div>                  

<script>
window.onload = function() {
window.setInterval(controllaAmicizie, 2000); 
controllaAmicizie();
};
</script>";}

else return "<div id='friend_request' class='hide'></div>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
    window.setInterval(controllaAmicizie, 2000); 
    controllaAmicizie();
    };
    </script>";
}
```

The JS code (i've corrected only this function)

```
function riempi_friend_request(richiesta) {

var div = document.getElementById("friend_request");

if(richiesta != 0){

  if (div.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
  div.style.visibility = 'visible';
  div.style.display = 'block';
} 
else {
  div.style.visibility = 'visible';
  div.style.display = 'block';
}   

 div.innerHTML = "<p><a class='alert' href='friend_request.php'>" +   richiesta + "</a></p>";   
}


else if (richiesta == 0) {

   richiesta = "Non hai nuove richieste di amicizia";
   div.innerHTML = "<p><a class='alert' href='friend_request.php'>" + richiesta + "</a></p>";

}

else return;

}
```

And the PHP code

```
<?php 

include("functions/layout_functions.php"); 
include("functions/db_functions.php");

$mysqli = connetti_db();
session_start();

$query = "SELECT * FROM amici WHERE id_ricevente =".$_SESSION['id']." AND      user_ricevente='".get_user()."' AND confirmed = '0'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if (mysqli_num_rows ($result) == 1) {

    echo "Hai ".mysqli_num_rows ($result)." nuova richiesta di amicizia";
    $_SESSION['request'] = "Hai ".mysqli_num_rows ($result)." nuova   richiesta di amicizia";

}

else if (mysqli_num_rows ($result) > 0) {

    echo "Hai ".mysqli_num_rows ($result)." nuove richieste di amicizia";
    $_SESSION['request'] = "Hai ".mysqli_num_rows ($result)." nuove     richieste di amicizia";

}

else if (mysqli_num_rows ($result) == 0) {

    echo "0";
    unset($_SESSION['request']);// = "Nessuna nuova richiesta";

}
disconnetti_db($mysqli);

?>
```

Thanks to everyone for advices and help!!